# PHP ionCube encoder file not working

Tags: php, encoding, ioncube

I have encoded my php code with ionCube encoder. It's working fine on
starting days after encoding, but now when I run my project I got this
error

```
Fatal error: 
The encoded file G:\wamp\www\Nishant\index.php has expired. in Unknown on line 0
```

So, what's the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you purchased a license yet? If not and you are using their evaluation version, be aware that files expire after 36 hours. You can always re-encode after that time if you need to continue testing. For any production use though you must purchase a license.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past and all I needed to do was to purchase a license!